# Graphviz Double quotes and Parentheses in nodes

Tags: graphviz, image-graphviz

I want to show Double quotes and Parentheses in nodes.

Without using A[label="Rahul(A)"]. I want to show during Rahul(A) -> B

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way I know to do that (without label) is by enclosing the node name between double quotes, and escaping double quotes which are part of the node name:

This works:

```
"Rahul(A)" -> "Rahul \"B\"";
```

[image: graphviz output]

Comment: In java it is not coming like that.  This is what i am doing    :-    Graphviz gv = new Graphviz();
      gv.addln(gv.start_graph());
      gv.addln("A(SS) -> B;");
      gv.addln("D -> C \"YY\";");    I dont know y it is not working

Comment: If you use a special implementation/library, you should mention that in your question. Otherwise it's assumed you use the original graphviz implementation available on graphviz.org. This being said, you'd of course have to escape special characters one more time for java: `gv.addln("\"A(SS)\" -> B;")` for example.